# What are "%1" and "%2" in batch files?

Tags: windows, batch-file

What does the following **%1** means (in a .bat file)?

```
jsmin <%1 >%2
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It represents the first command line argument passed to the batch file.

If you run your batch file with:

```
myfile.bat firstArg secondArg
```

`%1` becomes "firstArg" and `%2` becomes "secondArg"

The related `shift` command shifts the position of arguments one to the left. Running `shift` once in a batch file will make "%1" value to be the second argument, "%2" becomes the third, and so on. It's useful for processing command line arguments in a loop in the batch file.

Answer (score 13):

`%1` is the first argument given, `%2` the second.

If you run the file with `foo.bat source.js destination.js`, the command run is `jsmin <source.js >destination.js`.